# Creating a MIPS instruction from binary in C / C++

Tags: c++, file-io, binary, hex, mips

I need to create a MIPs instruction from a name.bin file in C / C++

The only notable change in the instructions is that the first bit is a validation bit - 0 for invalid, 1 for valid

the format must display as such

1 00000 00001 00010 00011 00000 100000  ADD R3, R1, R2

I am using hexadecimal masks to find each part of the instruction ie: opcodeMask = 0x7C000000

however, I am having trouble implementing this idea and cannot figure out how to sort and print the binary code. Any insight would be greatly appreciated, Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by "sort the binary code"?

Comment: Sorry not sort, rather organize it into Validbit " " opcode " " rs.... and so on

Comment: You could use a `struct` or a `class` to organize the fields of the instruction.